# Attempts to install a new programmer on avrdude failing because of autom4te

Tags: installation, autotools, avr, autoconf, avrdude

I'm trying to install an additional programmer on avrdude. I intalled avrdude itself, but because it didn't have a makefile I had to do it part by part and it seems the additional programmer wasn't installed in the overall program.

The programs for installing the programmer are ones I downloaded offline from a website for making an avr programmer with a usb keyboard. You can see where I downloaded them about halfway down this starting with github on the page http://wiki.steve-m.de/hidkey_gpio. When I try to compile the hidkey.h or main.c files they complain that I don't have the file ac_cfg.h, when I try to configure the file ac_cfg.h.in, which is in the same folder, using autoconf with the -v tag it seems to stop part of the way through ending with

```
autom4te:                    '_AM_COND_ELSE' => 1,
autom4te:                    'AC_SUBST_TRACE' => 1
autom4te:                  }
autom4te:                ], 'Autom4te::Request' );
autom4te: formatting traces for          
`/var/folders/ss/h96gpqbd0dvf5h2gmgpb3lnh0000gn/T//am4tGmgfkZ/warnings': _m4_warn
autom4te: reading /var/folders/ss/h96gpqbd0dvf5h2gmgpb3lnh0000gn/T//am4tGmgfkZ/warnings
autom4te: creating -
autom4te: formatting traces for    
`/var/folders/ss/h96gpqbd0dvf5h2gmgpb3lnh0000gn/T//am4tGmgfkZ/patterns': m4_pattern_allow, 
m4_pattern_forbid        
autom4te: forbidden tokens: ^$
autom4te: allowed   tokens: ^$
```

and no new file is made by the program. I found a site in which a similar was described as a resulting from multiple versions of autom4te, so I deleted every version of autom4te except for the one in the auto tools bin. When I ran it again I had the exact same problem. Has anyone had a similar problem installing a programmer on avrdude? Is there a more obvious way to do that than the one I'm using?

Comment: The purpose of autoconf is to build the `configure` script.  Running the `configure` script should generate `ac_cfg.h` from `ac_cfg.h.in` (assuming the standard naming conventions are being followed).  If you have a configure script, you should run it and you do not need to run autoconf.  If you do not have a configure script, you should get one from a proper distribution tarball.  If the project does not provide a proper distribution tarball or a mechanism to get one without running  autoconf, file a bug.